"Incompatible dimensions for a grouped binary operation" error in computing anomaly using climatological data in Python
As a beginner in Python, I am trying to compute monthly anomalies of temperature from AIRS-based timeseries observations with reference to monthly climatological (1950-1980) data from ecmwf. AIRS data is a monthly data from 2010 to 2015. After regrinding the data (as they have different grid resolutions), I attempted to compute the anomaly in Python. However, the error I am getting is "incompatible dimensions for a grouped binary operation: the group variable “month” is not a dimension on the other argument". Below, I am appending a reproducible code chunk.
I attempted to use the following code in Python to obtain monthly anomalies from 2010 to 2015 with respect to the monthly climatology of ecmwf. I am also sharing the data link here.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import xarray as xr
import scipy

# import the target data
airs_temp_2010_15 = xr.open_dataset('temp_2010_15.nc')

# import the climatological data
climatology_ecmwf = xr.open_dataset('monthly_climatology_1950_1980.nc')

# essential to change the lon progression patten in compatible with airs target data
lon_name = 'longitude'  # whatever name is in the data

# Adjust lon values to make sure they are within (-180, 180)
climatology_ecmwf['_longitude_adjusted'] = xr.where(
    climatology_ecmwf[lon_name] > 180,
    climatology_ecmwf[lon_name] - 360,
    climatology_ecmwf[lon_name])

# reassign the new coords to as the main lon coords
# and sort DataArray using new coordinate values
climatology_ecmwf = (
    climatology_ecmwf
    .swap_dims({lon_name: '_longitude_adjusted'})
    .sel(**{'_longitude_adjusted': sorted(climatology_ecmwf._longitude_adjusted)})
    .drop(lon_name))
# finally rename the field again to longitude
climatology_ecmwf = climatology_ecmwf.rename({'_longitude_adjusted': lon_name})
print(climatology_ecmwf)

# let's change the grid resolution of the ecmwf climatology data
regrid_lon_axis_clim = np.arange(-180,180, 0.5)
regrid_lat_axis_clim = np.arange(-90,90, 0.5)

# apply the regridding over the climatology from ecmwf
regridded_clim_ecmwf = climatology_ecmwf.interp(longitude=regrid_lon_axis_clim, latitude=regrid_lat_axis_clim)
print(regridded_clim_ecmwf['t2m'].shape)

# regrid the target data as well to make sure the shapes are same for both the data
regrid_lon_axis = np.arange(-180, 180, 0.5)
regrid_lat_axis = np.arange(-90,90, 0.5)

# apply it over the airs temperature data
regridded_temp_2010_15 = airs_temp_2010_15.interp(Longitude=regrid_lon_axis,Latitude=regrid_lat_axis)
print(regridded_temp_2010_15['Temperature'].shape)

# Isolate one layer from target data which will be used as mask layer to mask all values of climatological data

regridded_temp_2010_15_1st_layer = regridded_temp_2010_15.isel(time=0)


# Mask the regridded climatology data at per regridded airs data
masked_regrid_clim_t2m = regridded_clim_ecmwf.where(regridded_temp_2010_15_1st_layer['Temperature'].values >0)
print(masked_regrid_clim_t2m)

# Now compute the anomaly
anom_2010_15 = regridded_temp_2010_15.groupby('time.month') - masked_regrid_clim_t2m


You are carrying out an x-y operation. This requires the dimensions to be compatible. However, you have grouped one of them, which results in incompatible dimensions. You need to ensure they are compatible

Thanks, Rob for your reply. However, I observed that if I make monthly climatology from 2010-2015 data itself and then use the same code for computing the anomalies, it works.  I have shared the data link above.
